# Find all possible Jordan canonical forms of $4\times 4$ complex matrices which satisfy the following three conditions simultaneously?

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Find all possible Jordan canonical forms of $4\times 4$ complex matrices which satisfy the following three conditions simultaneously：

1. $A$ is not diagonalizable;
2. $A$ has characteristic polynomial $(x-5)^2(x-1)^2$;
3. $A$ satisfies the equation $(A-5I)(A-I)^3=0.$

Comment: What's the stumbling block? Do you know what Jordan canonical forms look like? Do you know how they relate to diagonalizability? Do you know how they relate to the characteristic polynomial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

- From 1, deduce that at least one block has size $2$ or larger,
- From 2, deduce that both $5$ and $1$ are eigenvalues,
- From 3, deduce that the largest block associated with $\lambda = 5$ has size $1$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think the answer is ${\rm diag}{[A, B]}$, where $A={\rm diag}{[5, 5]}$ and $B=[\alpha, \beta]$ for $\alpha=[1~0]^t$ and $\beta=[1~1]^t$.

Comment: @YWang That is indeed the only possibility